# Why I can add into Set the same arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

I can add into Set exactly the same arrays, but Set mustn't add elements that already exist in this Set. Set must store only unique values. But Why am I able to add these?

let s = new Set();
s.add([1]);
s.add([1]);
s.add([1]);

console.log(s);   //Set(3) {Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)}

Comment: what language and framework are you using?

Comment: @scrappedcola, yes, exactly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the `Set` object in ES6 is that **the equality check is based on comparing the actual reference of inserted objects**. Thus, when inserting multiple Arrays with the exact same content, it treats them as non-identical as the underlying object reference differs. Same goes for other objects. Primitives on the other hand are compared based on their values.